# Bracket for values in dictionary python 3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, brackets

I am wondering how can I manage the bracket[] for the values of that key. For instance, a dictionary named "diamond" which contains = {'a':'Roger', 'c':'Rafael', 'b':'Roger'}. I am supposed to re-organize the data in diamond so that it would become rediamond = {'Rafael':['c'], 'Roger': '['a','b']'}.

My Code

```
def group_by_owners(files):
store = dict()
for key,value in files.items():
    if value in store:
        store[value]=(store[value], [key])
    else:
        store[value]=[key]
return store

files = {
'a': 'Rafael',
'b': 'Roger',
'c': 'Roger'
}   
print(group_by_owners(files))
```

My Output

```
{'Rafael': (['a']), 'Roger': ['b'],['c']}
```

Expected Output

```
{{'Rafael': (['a']), 'Roger': ['b','c']}
```

So if there is to be 3 values for Roger, it should organize like ['','',''] .

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

diamond = {'a':'Roger', 'c':'Rafael', 'b':'Roger'}

rediamond = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in diamond.items():
    rediamond[v].append(k)
```